# Resized windows partition in windows,and got to grub rescue commandline instead of grub when rebooting

Tags: 11.10, dual-boot, windows-7, grub2

I dual boot windows 7 and Ubuntu 11.10. I ran out of space in my linux partition, so I hopped over to the windows partition after unsuccessfully resizing the linux partition with gparted. I was using Easeus partition manager, and I resized the windows 7 partition. I selected the reboot after changes done option. Instead of seeing the regular purple grub menu, I get the grub rescue screen. I'd much appreciate it if someone could help me.

Answer (score 1):

As [posted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73774/cant-boot-into-ubuntu-keeps-returning-to-grub/73957#73957) [elsewhere](https://askubuntu.com/questions/77904/grub-wont-load-win7-unknown-file-system/77953#77953), reinstalling GRUB2 to the Master Boot Record tends to solve this sort of problem. You can do that using any of [these methods](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Reinstalling_GRUB2). However, you said that you unsuccessfully attempted to resize your Ubuntu system's partition. So before you write to the disk in any way, you might want to verify that this operation did not cause data loss. You can do this by booting from an Ubuntu live CD/DVD or USB flash drive and verifying that you can access your files. If you cannot find your Ubuntu partition anymore, and you had important documents in your Ubuntu system whose backups were not current, then you can follow the suggestions in [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery) to *attempt* to recover your data. (Generally, when dynamically resizing partitions, especially with third-party tools, it is advisable to ensure that all backups of documents and other important files are current.)