# Grub won't load Windows 7 (unknown file system)

Tags: 11.10, grub2, dual-boot, files, system

I recently installed 11.10 on a new partition on my Windows 7 PC, and it works perfectly. But when I want to boot Windows 7 from the grub boot menu, it just says `unknown file system, grub rescue`.

Windows recovery says there is nothing wrong with it, an I can access all the files through Ubuntu. The Ubuntu **Disk Utility** says that the Windows 7 partition file system is *NOT clean*.

How do I get my Windows 7 back?

Answer (score 1):

Reinstalling GRUB2 to the Master Boot Record using any of the methods detailed [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Reinstalling_GRUB2) usually solves this sort of problem.

Comment: I did that, and now for some reason nothing boots. Anyway, I did some more tinkering, and I think that it was Windows, and not grub, that was causing the problem. I think I'll just reinstall everything...

Comment: If you decide you do want to keep troubleshooting this problem, then please indicate which of the methods you used, and any details about error messages you saw while using it.